# How to enable WSS in "SOAP Mock Response"

Tags: soapui, ws-security

How to enable WSS in the "SOAP Mock Response" step? The WS-Security Status was FAILED.
Everything works fine in "SOAP Request" step.

[SOAP Mock Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g2Be.png)

Comment: Did you follow the documentation? If so, please add what you’ve tried and what is not working. See https://www.soapui.org/docs/soapui-projects/ws-security/

Comment: Yes, I have configured Incoming WS-Security Configurations. SOAP responses are validated correctly, but requests are not.